# error on ng generate service geolocation

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am creating a new project then a new service, I type:

```
ng generate service Geolocation
```

But got an error:

```
PS C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp> ng generate service Geolocation
Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
    at SchematicEngine.createContext (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:64:38)
    at SchematicImpl.call (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\schematic.js:35:38)
    at Promise (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\schematic-run.js:72:23)
    at Class.run (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\schematic-run.js:71:16)
    at Class.run (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\generate.js:149:33)
    at resolve (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)
    at Class.validateAndRun (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:240:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\_Project\mycoffeeapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:140:24)
```

I did npm install, but still no success, where is it coming from according to you ?

Thanks

Comment: im getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall [@angular/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli). Follow these steps:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried with npm install npm@latest -g it works perfect now, thanks all :)